# Mongodb how to aggregate the number of occurencies(count) of distinct values?

Tags: mongodb

I have a set with 2m hashtags. However only around 200k are distinct values. I want to know wich hashtags are more repeated on my data.

I used this to find how many times each hashtag is repeated on my dataset:

```
db.hashtags.aggregate([{ "$group": {"_id": "$hashtag","count": { "$sum": 1 }}}]);
```

However, I would like to save the values in a distinct collection only with the unique values and its correspondency number of occurency.

How should I do that?

Please, if possible provide me some information in order that I can UNDERSTAND how to do it not only the code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) pipeline operator to write the output of the aggregation to another collection.

```js
db.hashtags.aggregate([
    { "$group": {"_id": "$hashtag", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}},
    { "$out": "newcoll" }
]);
```

Note that this feature was added in MongoDB 2.6

Comment: Yes, I just did that. Thank you. I was trying to use $project but then I read about the $out on the Mondodb Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) the following will, for `hashtag` with multiple records, return the duplicate `hashtag` and the corresponding record count:

```
db.hashtags.aggregate([
   {
     $group: {
        _id: "$hashtag",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
     }
   },  
   { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } },   
   { $sort : { count : -1} },
   { $limit : 200 },
   { $out: "duphashtags" }
])
```

The `$sum` operator adds up the values of the fields passed to it, in this case the constant 1 - thereby counting the number of grouped records into the count field. The `$match` filters documents with a count greater than 1, i.e. duplicates. `$sort` sorts the most frequent duplicates first, and limit the results to the top 200. The [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator writes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline to a specified collection, say `"duphashtags"`.